# Nginx Config to see swagger on other system with out running project

Tags: c#, .net, nginx, swagger

I have a dotnet project and it has swagger

First I run it.

and I want to others connect to my system throw my system ip and see my swagger
How can i config my nginx config ?

Comment: Just look for a tutorial on how to use nginx with dotnet... The swagger should be displayed by default.

Comment: actully @Osama i reed document of that but still didnt work 
i can see my localhost:8080 in other pc but i cant see swagger

Comment: Can you swagger locally? Are you running in development or production env variable?